# CKEditor with Roxy fileman

Tags: roxy-fileman

Finally I was able to integrate Roxy file manager to CKEditor.and it works as a a charm.
When I moved it to mydomain online,An error message still showing while browsing files on the server.
It is about loading ajax php/dirtree.php error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and I just re-uploaded the entire "fileman" folder and it worked. Seems like there was some missing files.